# Why extern long int c not allowed?

Tags: c

When I do something like

```
typedef long a;
extern a int c;
```

It gives me error : `two or more data types in declaration specifiers`.Why?

**EDIT**

```
typedef long a;
extern a c;
```

works fine.So why not above?

Comment: It's meaningless to `typedef` `long` as `a` !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a typedef, not a macro. The compiler doesn't see `extern long int c`, it sees `extern a int c`, which contains two different types (`a` and `int`).

Comment: Please see  the EDIT above

Comment: The edit doesn't change anything. `extern a c` is a declaration of just one type still. The statement that actually matches your question would be `extern long int c`.

Comment: :So why does it not take it as "Hey ! I want to use a variable `c` that is of type `long int` declared elsewhere"?

Comment: For the exact reason explained in my answer, as well as Robert's. The compiler no longer associates the type `a` with the type `long` in this context. Note that the statement `long int c;` declares a variable with a single type, `long int`. Even though it takes two symbols to describe that type, it is still a single type.

Answer (score 8):

Because when you `typedef` something it becomes its own, completely new type.  It can't be used as a modifier now.

Answer (score 0):

a is already a long int. You are saying there is a type which is a long int, called a.

see http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/keywords.html#short for how long is an implied int

Answer (score -2):

Lsiebert give the right answer. When the base type is omitted from a declaration, int is assumed. So, long = long int. When you declare "extern a int c" compiler will covert it to "extern long int int c". That will cause an error.

Comment: On this site, one expresses agreement with an existing answer by upvoting it, something you will be able to do after just a few days of use. Your answer does not really add anything new to this 3-month-old question.